# Wrong tab opening with razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two tabs,one is "Compras" and other "Fiscal",when i open the aplication, if the users has the role "68" is should open the tab fiscal, otherwise open "Compras",the problem is that the currently way i`m doing when i open the tab Fiscal comes selected correct but it opens the tab Compras.

I check here the permission of the user.

```
ViewBag.isFiscal = false;
                    if (Web.Security.CustomPrincipal.CurrentUser().IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        if (Web.Security.CustomPrincipal.CurrentUser().IsInRole("68"))
                        {
                            ViewBag.isFiscal = true;
                        }
                    }
```

And here i try to open the tab Fiscal:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">

        <li class="@(ViewBag.isFiscal == false ? "active" : "" )">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#compras" data-etapa="78">Compras</a>
            </li>

    <li class="@(ViewBag.isFiscal == true ? "active" : "" )">
            @if (Model != null && Model.IdTemplate > 0)
            {
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#fiscal" data-etapa="80">Fiscal</a>
            }
            else
            {
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">Fiscal</a>
            }
        </li>
</ul>
```

But when i open with a user that has role 68 it opens like this:
[image]

It is marked Fiscal,but the content of the form is from the form Compras,the correct Fiscal is this:
[image]

Someone knows what i`m missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I was putting the tag active only in tab Compras,and now i do a verification to put the tag active in Compras or fiscal

```
<div id="compras"class="tab-pane @( (bool)Session["isFiscal"] == false ? "active" : "" )">
        @*<div id="compras" class="tab-pane active">*@
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-compras", id = "frmSaveCompras", action = string.Format("{0}/home/index", pathRoot) }))
            {
                @Html.Partial("_abaCompra", Model, ViewData)
            }
        </div>
    @if (Model != null && Model.IdTemplate > 0)
    {
        <div id="contabil" class="tab-pane">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AbaContabil", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-contabil", id = "frmSaveContabil", action = string.Format("{0}/home/AbaContabil", pathRoot) }))
            {
                @Html.Action("AbaContabil", "home", new { id = Model.IdItem, partial = (bool)ViewBag.partial, hash = (string)ViewBag.hash })
            }
        </div>

        <div id="fiscal"  class="tab-pane @((bool)Session["isFiscal"] == true ? "active" : "" )">>
            @Html.Action("AbaFiscal", "home", new { id = Model.IdItem, partial = (bool)ViewBag.partial, hash = (string)ViewBag.hash })
        </div>
    }
```